# How to remove list from site when spfx web part removed?

Tags: javascript, development, spfx-webparts, delete-list, sp-online

Modern SPFx web part creates a new list 'abc' using code when it is added to site contents.

Now I want to remove list 'abc' automatically when web part is removed from site contents(using code not manually).

How can I achieve this?